# Create an infinite curved random trail

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, infinite-scroll

I am searching a way to create an infinite curved trail that will generate points randomly, and that the player will walk on the trail and always face the direction that the trail is going (2d game)

like this image here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofJun.png)

I really searching google and struggling to find an answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a line renderer for the curve. Keep adding new points ahead, delete the old ones and move the camera along to create the illusion of an infinite curve. When the line has gone too far, move all points and the camera back to places near the origin.

If you want to create smooth curves, you can smooth out the line using methods like averaging the points.

Useful links:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Floating_Origin

https://forum.unity.com/threads/easy-curved-line-renderer-free-utility.391219/

Hope you find them useful!